# the songs order when playing a LP in Rythmbox is not in order of the album

Tags: rhythmbox

how can I do that when trying to play a album in rythmbox is not putting the songs in oreder of number. it just put them in random order.
how can I fix that?
thanks

Comment: How are you playing the album? Is this from an inserted CD or a CD that you ripped?

Comment: I am playing them from my external hard disk.

Comment: Check to see if you have shuffle turned on by mistake. Also, please post a listing of your songs (add to the question).